# group calendar webpart not showing events in SharePoint online modern site

Tags: calendar, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

I have added a group calendar into my communication site and my team site. nothing is showing. I have added an event directly to the team calendar and can see the entries. When I go to the team site calendar, it doesn't show at all in a Web Part

Thanks in Advance

Comment: All good . fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was selecting the wring calendar when creating an new event.
Make sure you select the correct one